# Android - Store an action in LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I have a dialog system in my app, in which I build some of them at runtime, using a model I pass inside liveData to the UI.
Is it possible to store an action (lambda or something else) inside this model and pass it to liveData without taking the risk of memory leaks?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, no. Any reference (direct or indirect) that is used inside the lambda/functional object is *captured* so it cannot be released to the garbage collector until that lambda is released. So, for instance, if you pass something like `Runnable { myContainerView.visibility = View.GONE }` to your LiveData in the ViewModel,  it will leak the ViewGroup and all the views inside it.

Passing functions like this to your ViewModel would not be useful anyway. If the screen rotates or a Fragment is recreated, the functional objects in your ViewModel will be referencing out-of-date elements from the destroyed Fragment so you won't see anything happen if the function is invoked.

What you might consider instead is creating an enum that lists names representing all the possible lambda functions for a particular screen. The functions can be created when you need them, and you can safely store just the enum values in your LiveData.